# Linked list: Difference between "node* head=new node" and "node* head"

Tags: c++

I am creating a link list of size n entered by user.Here when I just initialize the header the output is perfect but when I declare it as well output has two zeroes appended.

For size=5 If I write node* head=new node; output is 432100 and if I write just node* head output is 43210. Why is that?

```
/* I am creating a link list of size n entered by user
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: neha
 *
 * Created on February 2, 2014, 12:39 AM
 */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
node* head=new node; //<--------------here
void PushFront(int value) //Inserting nodes at front of link list
{
    node* newNode= new node;
    newNode->data=value;
    newNode->next=head;
    head=newNode;

}

void Print() //printing the inserted nodes
{
    node* temp= new node;
    temp=head;


    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<< temp->data;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
int size,i;
cout<<"Enter size of linked list"<<endl;//Asking user to enter the size of linklist
cin>>size;
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
PushFront(i);
}

Print();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't write the question in the title.

Comment: It is because you created an extra node when you did `node* head = new node`. When you did `node* head`, you just created a pointer to a node, and not a new node itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just declare `node* head`, then the value of `head` is undefined ("junk") and you should refrain from using it.

An additional problem in your code is at:

```
node* temp= new node;
temp=head;
```

Not sure what you're trying to do by setting `temp = something` and then `temp = something else`. Obviously, the first assignment is useless, because it is overridden by the second assignment. And in this specific case, it leads your program to memory leaks, as you "lose" the dynamically-allocated memory pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Both your cases are undefined.

In your former case,

```
node* head=new node
```

head points to a new node whose next is uninitialized. This would mean `head->next = <Garbage>`.

```
       _________
      |DATA|NEXT|
head->|----|----|
      |Junk|Junk|      
      |____|____|

After 1st Insert

       _________    _________
      |DATA|NEXT|  |DATA|NEXT|
head->|----|----|  |----|----|
      |  0 |----|->|Junk|Junk|      
      |____|____|  |____|____|


After nth Insert

       _________      _________    _________
      |DATA|NEXT|    |DATA|NEXT|  |DATA|NEXT|
head->|----|----|    |----|----|  |----|----|
      |  n |----|...>| 0  |----|->|Junk|Junk|      
      |____|____|    |____|____|  |____|____|
```

In your second case

```
node* head;
```

head now points to some undefined value.

```
head->Junk

After nth Insert

       _________      _________   
      |DATA|NEXT|    |DATA|NEXT|  
head->|----|----|    |----|----|  
      |  n |----|...>| 0  |----|->Junk
      |____|____|    |____|____|
```

Both the cases, are similar, except that in the former cases, it just iterates to a blank node, after which the behavior becomes undefined.

Second case, is similar to the former except there is no blank (uninitialized) node.

**Solution**

```
node* head=nullptr;
```

Declare and initialize your head to `nullptr`

```
head->nullptr

After nth Insert

       _________      _________   
      |DATA|NEXT|    |DATA|NEXT|  
head->|----|----|    |----|----|  
      |  n |----|...>| 0  |----|->nullptr
      |____|____|    |____|____|
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your code is invoking undefined behavior when you access a pointer that doesn't point to a valid memory. When you invoke undefined behavior, anything can happen, including your code working correctly.

If you don't set the pointer at the start, then its value is undefined.

In your former case, your accessing an invalid pointer when you try and read the values inside of first head you create. Because you never set the value of `node* next;` then it is set to undefined value and when it tries to access the value your program crashes.

An easy fix for this is to add a constructor that sets the value

```
node() : data(0), next(nullptr){}
```

---

Another issue with your code is here

```
node* temp= new node;
temp=head;
```

You are unnecessarily creating a node using dynamic memory but you never delete it. Change your code to this

```
node* temp = head;
```

Comment: It is annoying when you get down voted without a reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the head nod with this code -- node* head=new node; --then you have to initialize the initial value of head node to NULL other wise it will take zero(0) i.e., head = NULL;
as,

```
    int main()
{
    head = NULL; // <<------Here
    int size,i;
    cout<<"Enter size of linked list"<<endl;
    cin>>size;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
    PushFront(i);
}
```

Just put one extra line in your above code and it runs .

Comment: This solution is similar to the one of the options that the asker provides, but does not answer the question posed. The question is about *why* this solution causes the output to be correct.